# Вытащить видео с youtube по id-автора

Tags: javascript, youtube

Добрый день.
Кто-то сталкивался с youtube api?

Не поделитесь ссылкой на документацию/примеры как можно вытащить список видео определенного пользователя по id этого пользователя?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял: id автора = его логин.
Я решил это таким образом:

```
var author_name='stevesattlerfilms';   //будем вытягивать видео этого автора

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author='+author_name+'&max-results=10',      //максимум 10 штук
    type: 'get',
    success: function(callback){
        var Events=$(callback).find('entry');   //ответ возращает нам xml документ, так что парсим его по тегу entry

        $(Events).each(function(){

            var link=$(this).find('id').text();  //в каждом теге находим тег id, в нем вшит адрес на видео
            console.log(link);

        })
    }
})
```